# How to create C style union in java?

Tags: java, c

I have to convert one of my code segment from C to java. Code is given below.

```
union commandString{
    char commndStr[20];
    struct{
        char commnd[4];
        char separator1;
        char agr1[5];
        char separator2;
        char arg2[3];
        char separator3;
        char additionalArg[5];
    };
};
```

I don't want to use any explicit parser or I do not want to use

```
System.arraycopy
```

method.
Is there any way to do that in my preferred way?

Comment: Well, if you really want to do this with C constructs that Java deliberately doesn't provide, you could write C code and call it through the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). I wouldn't recommend it, though. Why not write helper methods to extract each part of `commndStr`?

Comment: I have managed to make it work. But out of curiosity I asked this question, whether there is a way.

Comment: "Directly translating idioms from one language to another is a donkey thing. Instead of writing C in Java you should be asking what the best way of parsing a string in your format is."

I asked this out of curiosity, I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best library for doing [Struct and Union](http://javolution.org/) would be Javolutions which has been around for many years.  These were designed to do this.

I suggest if you are going to use these Unsafe you wrap it up in a library which abstracts it away.  This can avoid continuously running into bugs which crash your JVM (and I mean crash in the sense a C programmer would understand)

I have a library called Java-Lang which allows you to do the sort of things Java doesn't normally allow such as 63 bit sized off heap and memory mapped, thread safe off heap operations, sharing of memory between JVM on the same machine. And as I said, I use my own library to abstract away use of Unsafe.

Answer (score 12):

The Java language does not support unions or direct control memory layout the way that languages like C do directly.

However Oracle does offer a backdoor that was added in Java 5 that can be used by using the class sun.misc.Unsafe.  It takes a bit of work, the full details have been documented by Martin Thompson on his [blog](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/compact-off-heap-structurestuples-in.html).

The other option would be to write it in C and access it from Java as native functions via [JNI](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).

Comment: Ughhh ... I wouldn't use Unsafe for that.  Too many ways to shoot your feet off ...

Comment: No need to use Unsafe directly.  The closest thing to C Structs is the Structs library from Javolution. http://javolution.org/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html which also supports http://javolution.org/apidocs/javolution/io/Union.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey, It seems Javolution in pretty appealing, Let me check, Thanks anyway.

Comment: @stephen, every time one uses the Jdk the odds are that unsafe is being used under the hood.  For example atomicboolean or readwritelock.  If one takes the time to learn how to use unsafe, and accepts its risks then there is little reason to avoid it.  There are debates going on to move parts of unsafe into the core language and Apis.  However  PeterLawrey said it well, put it behind an abstraction and reuse.  Peter has done some excellent work in this area, and I second his recommendation of looking at javolition and his own java lang.

Comment: @ChrisK Sorry but your JNI link is dead; could you update it please?

Answer (score 1):

Reading about the Javolution Union led me to ByteBuffer, which can be used as a Union.  Being an Abstract Class with only one provided class, you may need to create a temp file using File.createTempFile(), a RandomAccessFile(File,"rw"), a FileChannel RandomAccessFile.getChannel(), a MappedByteBuffer FileChannel.map().  It has controls for whether you want a big endian (default) or little endian relationship of bytes to other types.  If you just need one Union for mapping types to bytes, such as for a trie, this would suffice.